# How to define typescript types about axios packaging

Tags: typescript

```
class Request {
  instance: AxiosInstance

  constructor() {
    this.instance = axios.create({ ... })

    return this.instance // at return ts error
  }
}

const request = new Request()

export default request
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wP2V.png)

When I want to encapsulate an axios instance with class, but the typescript says: Property 'instance' is missing in type 'AxioInstance' but required in type 'Request'

Comment: It feels like you shouldn't be returning anything from the constructor.  From reading the docs, if you return a non-primitive value from the constructor that is what is returned from instantiating that class.  So in your case, when you call a new Request, instead of getting an instance of Request, you're getting an instance of Axios.  Types script seems to be complaining correctly because a Request has an instance property but an instance of Axios probably does not.

Comment: But when I generate an instance, `const request=new Request(). instance` becomes like this. I have to write an extra `.instance` every time, and I have to generate many instances. I don't want to write `.instance`, but I want to get the AxiosInstance instance I want

Comment: Perhaps a class is not what you want then?  Why not just use a regular function that returns the axios instance?

Comment: It seems that we can only do as you said. I want the code to be more elegant, but my current abilities are not up to par